# Google Translate Arabic Font

Tags: fonts, arabic

Does anyone know the name of the font Google Translate uses for Arabic Script? It is not the default font, but it shows up from time to time for some reason, when you keep translating words.

Here is a sample:

[image]

Comment: I'm not sure whether the usual sources for font identification work for Arabic - see https://graphicdesign.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2366 - but whichever font it is, it's already on your computer, so that's going to narrow it down massively. This is also going to depend on your OS. This is what I get on Mac - https://i.stack.imgur.com/d1UFF.png My knowledge of Arabic is zero, so idk if they look the same.

Comment: @Tetsujin I am on a Mac too and I get the font you get normally — the fonts are very different. When I translate from Arabic to English, the font sometimes changes to the one in the picture. I haven't really pinpointed what triggers this exactly. I checked the Font Book and looked through all the Arabic fonts, but I haven't seen this one. I will try the font identification too. Thanks!

Comment: Is it possible to: right-click the text, choose *Inspect*, switch to the *Computed* tab, scroll down and see the font under *font-family*?

Comment: The font is Google Noto Naskh Arabic. I used the WhatFont extension for Chrome to find this. Thanks so much @Tetsujin!